# Search in tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, search

I have tow arrays in a `TableViewController`. One array with images and one array with titles.

```
_ArrayTitle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cat",@"Dog",@"Gnat", nil];
_ArrayImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cat.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dog.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gnat.jpg"], nil];
```

And I have `searchdisplayController`.

```
 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
      NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

      _searchResults = [_ArrayTitle filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

I want get result when write "Cat" in `searchBar` that Title`@"Cat"` situate with image `@"Cat.jpg"` in one cell when I searching.

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Cat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Dog"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Gnat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:2];
    }
    }
```

This code doesn't work. When I write "Cat", "Dog" or "Gnat" I get "Cat.jpg" in all cell. Please help me.

Comment: substitute isEqual with  isEqualToString: . Then check the results.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:

Comment: It is strange.It should have changed . Put a break point in the code and see the values of respective variables and see which condition is executed.From your scenario first condition is executed every time.

Comment: Add your code in question. I get first condition("Cat.jpg") when I write "Dog" or Gnat". But It is not right. When I write "Dog" I should receive "Dog.jpg" or when I write "Gnat" I should receive "Gnat.jpg".

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Why would changing `isEqual:` to `isEqualToString:` change the result? If the sender and the argument are both strings, using `isEqual:` works just fine.

Comment: @User FYI - this is a terrible way to code this. You shouldn't be hardcoding all of these strings and index numbers. What happens if you add more animals? What if the sort order changes?

Comment: Yes @rmaddy I thought it was for comparing pointers addresses. but it is protocol method and subclass can implement it according to the standard of equivalence of instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements are not what you mean to say. Change:

```
if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Cat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Dog"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if ([[_ArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Gnat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:2];
    }
```

to:

```
if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Cat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Dog"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Gnat"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_ArrayImage objectAtIndex:2];
    }
```

You want to see what title is in the search result at the index path then match that title to an image.